# How can I connect to a community server on Minecraft Xbox One Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console

I want to join the Hypixel server, but I can’t figure out how to add it.

Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't find an official source, From what I've been able to find on the forums it appears that Hypixel **only** supports the PC version of Minecraft:

> **TR:** Is there a way to connect to your server and play minecraft with xbox one? I looked but could not see a way to do so. does it only work on pc version?
>
> **MylesMor (MVP):** You can only connect to Hypixel on a computer, sorry.
> <sub>[Source](https://hypixel.net/threads/xbox-one.376109/)</sub>

> **GoodLife76 (MVP)**: When it comes to [Minecraft] xbox, it doesn't really have an ability for minigame servers. You can open a multiplayer world in survival or creative for your friends, but that's pretty much it. Also, a world on [Minecraft] xbox can have at maximum 8 people.
> <sub>[Source](https://hypixel.net/threads/hypixel-xbox-server.20651/)</sub>